# Firebase Database could not save EditText string or String text,

Tags: android

Firebase real time database could not save EditText string or String test_case = "this is test case message" in setValue,but it is successfully saving databaseReference.child(id_key).setValue("given string text");

```
                 final Text_Strings text_strings = new Text_Strings(user_name, id_key, title_m, question_m);



               // to save elements database referefernce called
                    databaseReference.child(id_key).setValue(text_strings, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                        if (databaseError != null) {
                            Log.d("Data could not be saved ", databaseError.getMessage());
                        } else {
                            // it is always saying data
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data saved  succcessfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                    // to save id_key for test cases
                databaseReference.child(id_key).setValue(test_case);
           /// to save string elements for test cases
                databaseReference.child(id_key).setValue("given string text");



            }
        });

  // return view
        return  view;
    }
}
```

;

Comment: where have you declared and initalised your test_case string, it might be possible testcase is null that's why it is not storing string

Comment: it is just simple test case to check, which is this      String test_case = "this is test case message"; databaseReference can save even this test_case, it is only saving  databaseReference.child(id_key).setValue("given string text"); kind of given string inside, I don't know why this happending

Comment: You're overwriting the same value with the second `child(id_key).setValue` call

Comment: if you mean this two  databaseReference.child(id_key).setValue(test_case);
           /// to save string elements for test cases
                databaseReference.child(id_key).setValue("given string text");
, they are only for test cases

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are in test mode or applied read write rules correctly .

You can refer to Docs for Read and Write data in Firebase Realtime Database : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Please paste you complete activity code to better understand your problem.